# What's a Craft way to achieve extra info on specific relationships?

Tags: relations, content

For example, say I have two sections:

1. Services
2. Locations

I make an `entries` field called "Services" and add it to the Locations field group, so that on a Location entry you can add `n` number of services.

What if I want a little bit of extra info that's unique to that particular pairing?

So, I have a location page called "Boston, MA" and a Service called "Window Washing". Using my `entries` field, I create a relationship on my "Boston, MA" page to the "Window Washing" Service.

However, I want to show a note with this particular relationship that we don't do Skyscraper windows in this location. It's Extra Info for this relationship only and it's variable.

How would you solve this problem in Craft?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I've come up with is to add a Matrix field that has two fields:

1. Text Input
2. Entries Field

Add that field to the "Services" field layout. Then you could add a lookup on the "Boston, MA" page when you iterate over related Services. Do a lookup and say, do they have a Matrix entry that is associated with this entry, and pull in the Extra Info as appropriate.